# How to automatically send email when process is using more than xxxMbit/s

Tags: email, cron, bandwidth

I haven't found anything for that. How could I automatically send an email (via crontab) with the ID of the process, the user & finally what's the name of the process for example when this process is using more than 100Mbit/s of bandwidth (or 10k PPS for example) ?

Thanks for help,
Olivier

Comment: Would restricting the amount of available bandwidth you give the process be a more suitable approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find something to do this for you an option is to write script that utilizes a few tools and throw it in cron if you like:

1.Use iptraf to print the traffic on each port to a log file

2.read the log file for the 1000Mbit/s bandwidth limit and grab the port that is using it

3.lsof the port to find the process using it.

4.mail the port and ID to whomever.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is first what you need do automatically.
You need some monitoring tool that can monitor and alarm when some values are exceeded.
You ditn't write about operating system, then I tell you about monitoring tools for linux.
You can use munin , this is very easy for use, but not scalable so high.
Zabbix is more scalable. For monitoring networks you can use Nagios or MRTG. Cacti is usable. Simply select one of them.
If you need more, read article how to monitor ubuntu:
http://www.ubuntugeek.com/bandwidth-monitoring-tools-for-ubuntu-users.html

Under some monitoring tool usually you can configure email triggers, that send email to specified users when something is wrong. somethings wrong what you defined :)

It isn't goog idea to develop wheel again. Use monitoring :P